# cannot find partial views under areas shared folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a layout page under

> ~/Areas/Admin/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Now inside that I have a section where I was supposed to render a partial view . So what I did inside `_layout.cshtml` was  to provide `@Html.RenderAction("Sidebar")`

The controller is actually basecontroller which is inherited to all other controllers . as

```
[OutputCache(Duration=60)]
public partial class BaseController : Controller
{       
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public virtual ActionResult Sidebar()
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

Now this Controller is supposed to be interited by all X,Y , Z controllers so the childaction `Sidebar` would be available to all of them so that `@Html.Renderaction("Sidebar")` doesnt have the trouble to find the child action to be rendered .

Now the problem is the partialview path is under `/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Partials/Sidebar/cshtml`

I have also configured the razor view engine to find under that particular `/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Partials/Sidebar.cshtml`. And registered it under global.asax.

But its unable to find the partial view and giving the error as

```
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Admin/Sidebar.aspx
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Admin/Sidebar.ascx
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Sidebar.aspx
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Sidebar.ascx
~/Views/Admin/Sidebar.aspx
~/Views/Admin/Sidebar.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Sidebar.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Sidebar.ascx
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Admin/Sidebar.cshtml
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Admin/Sidebar.vbhtml
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Sidebar.cshtml
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Sidebar.vbhtml
~/Admin/Sidebar.cshtml
~/Views/Admin/Sidebar.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Sidebar.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Sidebar.vbhtml
```

My custom razor view engine is

```
public class LocalizedViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    ///{0} = View Name
    ///{1} = Controller Name

    private static readonly string[] NewPartialViewFormats = new[] {
        "~/Areas/Admin/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml"
    };
    private static readonly string[] NewViewLocationFormats = new[] { 
        "~/Areas/Admin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" 
    };

    public LocalizedViewEngine()
    {
        base.ViewLocationFormats = 
base.ViewLocationFormats.Union(NewViewLocationFormats).ToArray<string>();
        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = 
base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(NewPartialViewFormats).ToArray<string>();
    }
}
```

And My global.asax contains

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new LocalizedViewEngine());
```

But its unable to find the partial view under tha `~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Partials/Sidebar.cshtml` . Where am I going wrong ?